# Group and Sum Many to Many Django ORM

Tags: python, django

I have the next model of a rent movies store. That is, the table UserRating stores the rating of a movie related to a user. I am trying to make a view where it is possible to get the corresponding **image** of the movies sorted by rating. I know how to sort by rating (UserRating.objects.values('movie_id').annotate(dcount=Sum('vote')).order_by('dcount')). My problem now is? how to get the image of these movie_id's that I getted?

```
class Movie(models.Model) :
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, primary_key=True)
    movie_image = models.ImageField()

class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, primary_key=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class UserRating(models.Model) :
    vote = models.IntegerField()
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('user', 'movie'),)

    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, in Django, if you ultimately want to return data about a certain model, you have to go through the object manage for that model. In this case, you are looking for a field from Movie, so start off using the Movie object manager.

An automatic inverse-relation gets built for your FK relationships, which is usable in the ORM. The ORM code ends up looking like this (I ordered by Votes descending, because I assume you want most-voted movies first):

```
Movie.objects.annotate(votes=Count('userrating')).order_by('-votes').values_list('movie_image', flat=True)
```

And the resulting SQL is:

```
SELECT "sample_movie"."movie_image" FROM "sample_movie"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "sample_userrating" ON ("sample_movie"."title" = "sample_userrating"."movie_id")
GROUP BY "sample_movie"."title"
ORDER BY COUNT("sample_userrating"."id") DESC;
```

Lastly, I used Count instead of Sum because I assume you want to know how many votes a movie has, not the sum of all the primary keys :)